# NetSuite Historical Search Results

Tags: search, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a search that shows the number of cases that are open today (would be run on a Monday morning), the number that were open last Monday morning, and the number that were open the Monday morning before that.

Problem is, I can not find any way of telling the search to basically pretend it was last week for these results, and the week before for those results.

I can't use any fields that exist on the forms, as they would never point to the date that we are viewing the search.

The logic seems easy:

```
count(cases open now)
count(cases open last Monday @ 08:00)
count(cases open two weeks ago Monday @ 08:00)
```

The NetSuite solution is just evading me.  Anyone else ever run into this?  Seems like it would be pretty common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the fact that anything that was open last Monday is anything that was created before last Monday and not closed before last Monday.
Open Last Monday = date created < last monday AND (date closed is empty or date closed > last monday)

Comment: That's a good thought.  I'll try that tomorrow and see if that could work.  You definitely might be on to something.  Thanks.

Comment: Marking this as correct.  It did work for me.  I just set a CASE WHEN statement to look at {today}-7, and am checking the open and closed dates against that.  Simple, easy solution.  Thanks!